# Check if Flash object has method from within JavaScript

Tags: javascript, flash, swfobject, externalinterface

I am calling an ActionScript object method from within a JavaScript function, however I can't be sure the flash object has that particular method. If the flash object does not supply the method in question I end up with an `Error calling method on NPObject!`.

How can I check whether the flash object supplies the method in question? I tried to wrap it in a type check like this:

```
if(typeof flashObj.myfunction() === 'function') {
    //do it
}
```

But I still end up with:

```
Error calling method on NPObject!
if(typeof flashObj.myfunction() === 'function') { 
…
```

Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are actually calling the function in your comparison.

Instead of this:

```
if(typeof flashObj.myfunction() === 'function') {
    //do it
}
```

use this:

```
if(typeof flashObj.myfunction === 'function') {
    //do it
}
```

Comment: Oh blimey, how embarrassing :)